# On going back to the previous Activity my media progress get lost (seekBar and media player progress)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar

Actually i have 2 activities , in the main activity i am displaying all the songs using recycler view and setup an onClickListner on it, and when someone taps on it , it launches a new activity(MediaPlayer Activity) and start playing the song along with media controls like (paly, pause and seekBar).

But when i get back to the main activity and click on a button (which basically takes to the MediaPlayer activity again) all the mediaPlayer and seekBar progress are gone also the (play, pause, next and previous buttons) are not responding to the clicks.

This is from where i am  starting the MediaPlayer activity :

```
 @Override
    public  void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.Song.setText(mData.get(position).title);
        holder.Artist.setText(mData.get(position).artist);


        Glide.with(mcontext).load(mData.get(position).imagePath).
                placeholder(R.drawable.unknown_art).into(holder.PhotoId);


        holder.Options.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(mcontext, "You clicked on options", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.RL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(mcontext, MediaPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("songPosition",position);
                mcontext.startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
```

These are the codes in the MediaPlayerActivity :

```
public class  MediaPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=null;
     static int pos=0;
     SeekBar seekBar;

     @Override
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_media_player);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        pos = intent.getIntExtra("songPosition",pos);

        seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        Button next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        Button previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        final Button play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_3);
        final TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.songInfo);

         info.setText(VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.mData.get(pos).title);

         if(mediaPlayer!=null&&mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

             mediaPlayer.stop();
             mediaPlayer.reset();
             mediaPlayer.release();
         }
         playMedia(pos);


         next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 try {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.reset();
                     mediaPlayer.release();
                     playMedia(++pos);
                     info.setText(VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.mData.get(pos).title);
                 }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                     Toast.makeText(MediaPlayerActivity.this,"Already the last song!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         });




         previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 try {
                     mediaPlayer.stop();
                     mediaPlayer.reset();
                     mediaPlayer.release();
                     playMedia(--pos);
                     info.setText(VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.mData.get(pos).title);
                 }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                     Toast.makeText(MediaPlayerActivity.this,"Already the first song!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             }
         });



         play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                 if(mediaPlayer!=null&&mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){

                     play_pause.setText(R.string.mp_play);
                     mediaPlayer.pause();
                 }
                 else{
                     play_pause.setText(R.string.mp_Pause);
                     mediaPlayer.start();
                  }
             }
         });


    }

    public void playMedia(int pos){

        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(VerticalRecyclerViewAdapter.mData.get(pos).songPath);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                    seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setSeekbarProgress();
        onSeekbarChange();
        playNext();

    }

    public void playNext(){

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    playMedia(++MediaPlayerActivity.pos);

                }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                    Toast.makeText(MediaPlayerActivity.this, "Already the last song", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public void setSeekbarProgress(){

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                }
                catch (RuntimeException e){
                    Log.i("CRASH",""+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        },0,1000);
    }


    public void onSeekbarChange(){

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                if(b) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });
    }



}
```

And this  is where from i wanted to go back to the MediaPlayer Activity (on button click ) :

```
 mFloatingToolbar.setClickListener(new FloatingToolbar.ItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.music:

                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MediaPlayerActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                        break;

                    case R.id.pause :


                        break;
                    case R.id.next :
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;


                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      verticalRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(MenuItem item) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you should write a service to handle the `MediaPlayer` functions which will run in background.

Comment: The song is running in the background, but seekBar progress get lost.